# when i use OnRowUpdated and OnRowUpdating.What is the use of these

Tags: asp.net, gridview, grid

I want to know the difference between `OnRowUpdated` and `OnRowUpdating`. I gave both `OnRowUpdated` and `OnRowUpdating` to `gridview`.
`OnRowUpdated` is not triggered. Only `OnRowUpdating` working fine

Plz clarify this.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is a good place to start -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowupdating.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowupdated.aspx

So to summarise -

The RowUpdating event is raised when a row's Update button is clicked, but *before* the GridView control updates the row.

The RowUpdated event is raised when a row's Update button is clicked, but *after* the GridView control updates the row.

Answer (score 0):

> They are both used for two different things. It depends on whether you are accessing the row before or after the update.